# Strange sound of Clutch when it is up and when starting the car from cold

Tags: clutch, volvo, cold-start, 850

The sound stops when I press it down or hold it more up.
The car is in Finland now so there is something like minus **-5 celcius** which causes the problem when the car is kept outside.

I will record the sound soon and add it here.

The car is 95-year Volvo 850 which has been hold before this winter in a garage.

**What can be the cause of the problem?**

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Is the sound coming from the ignition switch? Or from another location. Volvo's are built strong and are usually really good about the cold.

Comment: There was a mistake in my title. I mean Clutch, instead of switch. The one which you press with a pedal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect a worn clutch release bearing, or spigot bearing. How old is the clutch? Both bearings should be replaced when the clutch is replaced, and if it is the original clutch, they are now 18 years old...